# How can I implement grails Url Mapping for countries

Tags: grails

I have a little problem with my application , i want to implement this :domain/countries/controller/... 
But i dont know how can i do it. that is possible with url mapping?

Comment: Can you share an example? `domain/countries` is the text fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your UrlMappings:

```
     static mappings = {
  name contryURL: "/$domain/$country/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            //if you need them
        }
    }
```

This is assuming domain and country are parameters.